# Using multiple Runtime Libraries on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, webserver, microsoft-runtime-library

I am currently making a webserver that fetches data from a database and passes it to the API. I managed to make both of those things work separately but when I need to make them work together (my webserver queries the database, parses it in json, then passes it to the server), I'm running into a problem in an area I am quite unfamiliar with.

I used Casablanca for my API and Connector/C++ for the database connection. However in the Static Build section of [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html) it tells me that the Runtime Library should use the /MD compiler option. The problem is that for the webserver part of the program to work, it needs to be in the default /MDd.

Would it be possible to make one or the other work in either /MD or /MDd, and if not, what options do I have for my webserver to get the data queried from a database?

**EDIT** : this seems to only be a problem on debug and not on release. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924830/what-is-difference-btw-md-and-mdd-in-visualstudio-c) is the one that made me tick. I don't know if this is ethical, but at least it's working.

This can be closed.

Comment: Why are you writing a custom webserver instead of just using one of the *many* that already exist?

Comment: Right. This is for a school project, and even though we aren't required to code everything ourselves (meaning we can use APIs for sessions and things like that), I'd like to do a lot of it myself as to have as much knowledge when the time of the project review comes. Not only that but this also amounts to a lot of work I need to do, so I might as well do it since I have enough time.