# MFC application failing to build project even after shared dll specified? I tried all the ways I found on online but it still doesn't work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

```
#ifdef _DLL
#ifndef _AFXDLL
#error Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]
#endif
#endif
```

I am not knowing how to fix this error if someone could help me that would be great
I tried changing the mfc properties but still doesn't work

Comment: Properly format your code in the question and explain what you are trying to do. What are your `define` and what is you `MD` option. You won't get much help if you don't provide all required information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message Setting: Project Properties -> Advanced -> Use of MFC = "Use MFC in a Shared DLL" is in conflict with setting: Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library -> "Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)".

Make sure both are set as above. As an example you will get this error if trying to build with "Use MFC in a Static Library". Also make sure these settings are not being inherited in conflicting state.

[what is difference btw /MD and /MDD in VisualStudio C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924830/what-is-difference-btw-md-and-mdd-in-visualstudio-c/924854#924854)

Comment: still it doesn't work

Comment: yes it still doesn't work